# Is this concrete walkway, with bad chipping, salvageable?

Tags: concrete

I have lots of chipping on my walkway.  Is something like a concrete topper or resurfacer going to bring this back?  Planning wire brushing and shop-vaccing anything lose.  Should I just jackhammer it all up and start again?  Concrete was done long-long ago.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What we see here looks to me like degradation due to either a dry mix, overworking, or chemical damage. **It's not salvageable.** Repairs are unlikely to be durable and would require nearly as much effort as replacement.

I assume a couple things about this walkway for the sake of discussion:

- It's standard thickness--probably 4". All walks in my region are poured this thick to tolerate freezing, etc.
- It's on a suitable base. This would be inorganic gravel, crushed rock, or recycled concrete.

If true, take it out with a sledge hammer and a wheelbarrow. Then re-form with 4" rips of hardboard (use two layers of 1/4" if the inside curve proves challenging) and pour it again.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the degraded sections: there's so little left a small jackhammer would take it out in a few minutes. You could even just use a hammer drill, since it is so thin.

For the replacement you might consider digging down a few inches, laying a couple of inches of crushed gravel/hardscrabble as a base, compacting that, and then doing a four (*) inch pour. Less may survive but why not get a bit more likelihood of longevity.

(*) I had originally said three inches but @Isherwood pointed out that the photo is showing degraded concrete [ I had thought that were the underlaying substrate of gravel]. That was a surprise - showing more heavy degradation than I had expected. So yea let's go with the typical four here.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems from a bad job.

1. The concrete is way too thin to walk on it. It should be at least 2 inches thick.
2. The underlayer is wrong--it should be compressed crushed stone.

Yes you can repair that.

Comment: By repair did you mean replace?

Comment: The concrete is likely much thicker than just the surface layer we see. It's that badly degraded. And we have no idea what the substrate is. At any rate, this isn't salvageable.